# Why does pdflatex crash with the pdfpages packages, and is there anything I can do to prevent this?

Tags: pdfpages

I wish to append some pdf documents to the end of a larger document I'm writing, but find that using the `\includepdf` command provided by `pdfpages` always crashes pdflatex.

The following example exibits the behaviour:

First create a test pdf, which we will append to the main doc:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\begin{document}

This is some text

\end{document}
```

Then

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{pdfpages}


\begin{document}

  This is the text in the main doc.

  \includepdf[pages={~}]{test_pdf.pdf}

\end{document}
```

This causes pdflates to crash with a 'pdflatex has encountered a problem' message. In this case I'm using MikTeX 2.9 on windows XP Pro 32 Bit with Texniccenter 1.0 as my editor (although Texworks also fails, not that I think the editor has anything to do with it, but you never know). I haven't tried on other platforms. In case it's relevent I do not normally have admin access on this PC.

Is this a known problem, and is there a latex work around? I'm aware of other non-latex methods to append the pdfs if necessary.

Comment: You should be using `pages={-}` or `pages=-`, *not* `pages={~}`.

Comment: Hooray! I'm embarrassed that it was so simple, but also a bit dissappointed that this can actually crash pdflatex. If you put this as an answer below I'll give you the credit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message is

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file \protect \unhbox \voidb@x \penalty \@M \ {}.pdf):
 cannot find image file
```

which is caused by calling the option

```
pages={~}
```

rather than the correct

```
pages=-
```

I don't think there's a really safe protection against such errors.